# in my layouting with div tag sth is wrong

Tags: html, css, layout

hi i used div tag to layout my web page and i have a problem that there is about 2 more pixels free space which i marked it on 
[image]

and also i used these codes for progrraming it:

**CSS**:

```
.rightdiv {
height: 1200px;
width: 25%;
border: 1px solid;
float: right;}


.centerdiv {
height: 1200px;
width: 49.3%;
border: 1px solid;
float: left;}
```

And also i have to explain that i used 49.3% in right-div because if i use more percent it will go to next line.

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or please share the link of the working site..

Comment: First, just `css` code may be not enough, provide some `html` also. Second, problem can be here: `.centerdiv {...width: 49.3%;...}`, as percent roundup/down can give not pixel-perfect results.

Comment: if i give more than 49.3  next line is waiting for me.and for your second answer hwat kind of coding do uyou suggest as giving percent

Comment: @Lal its not a site its just for learning

Comment: You somehow will have to reproduce the issue for us to debug..

Comment: @mateenbagheri, I meant, floating point percentage is not reliable. You should make one of page fragments `stretchable`: i.e., make `right` div `25%` wide, `center` div - `50%`, and left div - stretchable. Then push right and center div's to right side of page with float, and left div - to left side. Or make left and right div's `25%` wide and center div - stretchable. That way you'll never face `next line is waiting for me` issue

Comment: @Lal look my prob is this: i lay outed my webpage with div tag i used the css wich i wrote it above and now there is about 2 or 3 more oixelx wich are free and empty but i want them to be linked to my centeer div

Comment: try removing your `float:right` and `float:left` combinations and instead use just any one of them. Try usinf `float:left` for all the divs and update me the result.

Comment: @lal thnks so much it worked tjere is no tick for your answer to i say that your answer worked thats strange

Comment: Oh great.. :) Added that as my answer @mateenbagheri..could you please mark the asnwer as accepted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `float:right` and `float:left` combinations and instead just use any one of them.

For now just use `float:left` for all the divs.